# programmatically edit articles in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am new to Joomla development, I am developing a website in which I have to use customize the articles (i know you will say develop a component or module) but I want to use articles any ways.

While google I found that Joomla stores  all the contents of articles in database.

but what I need is Is there any way to edit articles programatically(are there any PHP files for articles folders or so where i can eDit them) I have to add custom styles, menus and things like that to a certain article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say edit articles programmatically, do you mean edit the content of an article, or how it is presented and what else loads with it?

the former will require you to edit the db contents.

the latter means you need to look into how joomla's templating system works, which is most likely what you need to do. piece of further advice: modules have the ability to define class/id per instance, which will be very helpful for writing your css.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use custom PHP code in your articles, take a look at JUMI.